# Should we delete all tags that have fewer than 10 uses and have not been used in the past 2 years?

Tags: discussion

Often times, we see tags that have fewer than 10 uses and have had no uses for 2+ years. It is likely that people are unaware of them. So should we use a bot to autodelete tags like these?

Answer (score 9):

**No.**
If people are "unaware" of the tags, yet are asking queries that would otherwise fit those tags, the sensible solution would be to edit the query's tags as appropriate. It might also be a good idea to improve any relevant verbiage in the help center or tour regarding tag existence, function, and usage.